# Table not fully closed

Tags: tables

I have a table which I am trying to put in a paper but the left hand side is not closed. Can anyone help with this? Also there is a small gap in the middle of the table I would like to get rid of if anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabulated results}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Channel}& Channel this is \\
 \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{K O}}&
K1\\
    \multicolumn{2}{cl}{}&$K2$\\
    \hline
    \multirow{1Q}&H& r1$\\
   &H2&   r2\\
     &N& r3\\
      &X& $X_{x}$\\
      &X& $X_{y}$\\
    \hline
        \hline
    \multirow{2q}&H& r1\\
   &H&    r2 \\
     &N&  r3\\
     &H3& r4\\
      &X& $X_X$\\
      &X& $X_Y$\\
      &X& $X_Z$\\
    \hline
    DD& rd \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `DD& rd \\` only has two cells, you want `DD& rd &\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has many errors, not just the one @David Carlisle who  pointed out in his comment:

- \multirow has wrong syntax,
- missed (not paired) one `$`, it is not clear if are missed at other cell contents (`r2`, `r2` etc)
- missing vertical lines in `\multicolumn` commands
- correct document example (MWE: Minimal Working Example) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabulated results}
\label{tab:multicol}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Channel}    &   Channel this is \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{%
    \multirow{2}{*}{K O}}       &   K1              \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}          &   $K2$            \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{1Q} &   H       &   $r1$            \\
                    &   H2      &   r2              \\
                    &   N       &   r3              \\
                    &   X       &   $X_{x}$         \\
                    &   X       &   $X_{y}$         \\
    \hline
    \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{2q} &   H       &   r1              \\
                    &   H       &   r2              \\
                    &   N       &   r3              \\
                    &   H3      &   r4              \\
                    &   X       &   $X_X$           \\
                    &   X       &   $X_Y$           \\
                    &   X       &   $X_Z$           \\
    \hline
DD                  &   rd      &                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it is true that the table has many errors but is there a reason to keep them in place? Why is `r1` typeset in text mode and `r2` in math mode, say, and similarly for `K1` and `K2` and *many* other examples? I understand that this is the OP's code but you mention that you fix the mistakes, which I can hardly see.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, well, you can fix all I was missed. I just made code compilable and add missed vertical lines, what was OP question. Other I left to OP.

Comment: I am not interested in writing an answer if the problem is already solved in the comments.